# How to run an async/await task when application will be terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, activitykit, widgetliveactivity

I want to update or end a Live Activity when the application is terminated, but those functions are async, and anything inside `Task{ }` is not get called in the `applicationWillTerminate(_)` function.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    Task {
        if #available(iOS 16.2, *) {
            await LiveActivityManager.cancelAllRunningActivies()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried passing a group user default to the live activity, and live activity uses a timer to check the new value for every seconds, but timer on live activity is not get called.

Is there any way to update the live activity when the application is about to be terminated?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. It's only can be executed at most with background mode. When your app is terminated by user/system, it will no longer be in memory so it can not do anything further.

Comment: Forgive the question, but have you confirmed that `applicationWillTerminate` was even called? IIRC, there are scenarios where it will not be called at all.

Comment: @Rob I add a breakpoint to confirm `applicationWillTerminate` was get called, anything inside the `Task` is not get called.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the normal sequence now is that you get a notice that your app is going to be suspended, and then once suspended your app may be terminated without any warning. (It's possible to get an `applicationWillTerminate`, but it's actually the exception in modern versions of iOS .

Answer (score 4):

This works for me: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732418

```
class func stopSessionTimeoutAsync()
{
    print("Ending Live Activities")
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    Task
    {
        for activity in Activity<TimeoutActivityAttributes>.activities
        {
            print("Ending Live Activity: \(activity.id)")
            await activity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

Just remember to use `Task.detached` if the entire class is marked with `@MainActor`, otherwise anything inside the task will not be execute.

Comment: Task.detached is what did it for me, even without a @MainActor class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot to understand how to use the previous answer, the method name was pretty confusing for a beginner.

This works on iOS 17.3, you have to put it on your App class

```
import ActivityKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SomeApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("App will terminate")
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        Task.detached
        {
            for activity in Activity<TimeoutActivityAttributes>.activities
            {
                print("Ending Live Activity: \(activity.id)")
                await activity.end(nil, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
            }
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()
    }
}
```